# Docker compose run with specified platform

Tags: docker, docker-compose

my docker script has this line.

> docker-compose --file "$COMPOSE_FILE" up --detach --build --force-recreate

I would like to run it for specific platform, for example --platform=linux/amd64

How can I include the platform where it should run?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the compose file, within your service, you would set:

```
platform: "linux/amd64"
```

This is available in both the latest [compose spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#platform) and [version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#platform) of the compose file.

Comment: is this still working? `Unsupported config option for services.mysql: 'platform'`

Comment: Are you using v2.4 @JanBoehmer?

Make sure the top of your docker-compose.yml has: `version: '2.4'`

Comment: Make sure you are adding the `platform` line at the _service_ level, not at the _build_ level. See the examples at https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/05-services.md#platform Note: `platforms` also exists, and that is used at the _build_ level: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/build.md#platforms

Comment: @psq. Nice one!